# How to group rows by timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
id         created_at
=========  =========
1          1585461059805
2          1585461062502
3          1585461073123
4          1585461081885
...
```

The second column is a timestamp. I would like to combine sequences of rows without 5000 ms gap.

Is it possible to thin out the result of the SELECT query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `LAG` for this purpose:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(created_at, 1, created_at - 5001)
                  OVER (ORDER BY id) lag_created_at
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, created_at
FROM cte
WHERE created_at - lag_created_at > 5000;
```

Note that I use a default lag value of `created_at - 5001` to cover the edge case of the very first record.  This first record has no lag, but we still want to include it.